# align text label to right bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I want to **align text label to right** Using bootstrap 5
like when i type this code:

```js
<div class="form-floating text-dark text-end float-right">
  <input type="password" class="form-control text-dark" placeholder=" " id="password">
  <label for="floatingInput" class="float-right text-end">كلمة المرور</label>
</div>
```

The text is start from left
I want change it to right

I tried `.text-end`
And type css code

```css
.float-right {
    float: right;
}
```

But that not working for me

[image]

Comment: Where is `class="float-right"` in your HTML markup?

Comment: I tried used it with  input div but that not working,
and i tried it with label  and that not working

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Add a code snippet where you tried that and isn't working for you.

Comment: @pavel I will edit this question and you can show

Comment: @pavel
Modified

Comment: It works me, you're doing something wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/t9j2x3f0/

Comment: @pavel
try use bootstrap with it,
It is on the right side of the field
https://jsfiddle.net/26tocbfm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below css for `label`

```
label {
    text-align:right;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: That's Work
Thx

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP